# Binding grid to linq where date is stored as integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, infragistics

I want to bind a webdatagrid or radgrid to a linqdatasource. The date in the db as stored as an integer like so 20070205 (YearMonthDay).
When I try to convert the int to a date in the linq query like so

```
var q = from i in ICILOCs
select i.LASTRCPTDT.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I get an error:

> Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

I can load the results into memory with ToList() and then parse it. The problem is I will loose the efficient paging with the grid. 
Or I can parse it on ItemDatabound, the problem is that how will I set the filter for this field in the grid? It should a calendar dropdown, not an integer textbox.
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Why is the date not stored in the database as a Date field? Are you *sure* it's being stored as an integer? The error message suggests it's being stored as a Varchar or something similar...

Comment: Yes the date is stored as an integer

Comment: Then why does the error message suggest that the type of `i.LASTRCPTDT` is a string? And how would you expect `x.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` know what to do with an integer anyway?